# How to conditionally assign median value for a given group without a for loop in python?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, group-by, list-comprehension

I am trying to assign the median value of rp for each gvkey to every NaN value. I can do it using this for loop:

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if df.iloc[i]['rp']!=1 and df.iloc[i]['rp']!=0:
        df.iloc[i]['rp']=df['rp'][df['gvkey']==df.iloc[i]['gvkey']].median()
```

But there must be a way to do this without the for loop.

An example of the dataset is below:

```
gvkey     rp    cliff
1004.0    0     0
1004.0    0     0
1004.0    NaN   0
1005.0    1     1
1005.0    1     0
1005.0    0     1
1005.0    NaN   0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use, [`Dataframe.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `grpkey` and transform the column `rp` using `median`, then use [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to fill the missing values in column `rp`:

```
df['rp'] = pd.to_numeric(df['rp'], errors='coerce')
df['rp'] = df['rp'].fillna(df.groupby('gvkey')['rp'].transform('median'))
```

Result:

```
# print(df)
    gvkey   rp  cliff
0  1004.0  0.0      0
1  1004.0  0.0      0
2  1004.0  0.0      0
3  1005.0  1.0      1
4  1005.0  1.0      0
5  1005.0  0.0      1
6  1005.0  1.0      0
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am getting the DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
Maybe because for certain gvkey's the median is NaN? and for certain gvkeys are most likely all NaN?

Comment: Whats the dtype of `rp` column?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate median values using [DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) method over your gvkey column:

```py
median_values = df.groupby('gvkey').median()
```

Then you can use [DataFrame.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) method to fill all nan values with calculated medians. It should be noted, that fillna works with dataframe indexes, so you need to set new index (that used to calculate medians):

```py
df.set_index('gvkey').fillna(median_values).reset_index()
```

Method DataFrame.reset_index() is used to return 'gvkey' column back.

Comment: Wouldn't you then calculate and assign the median value of gvkey and not rp?

Comment: No, but it would be both filling nan values within 'rp' and 'cliff' field

Comment: ok, thank you, Shubham Sharma's answer does it specifically for rp which is what I needed.